# Button is not working after I used jQuery Dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, dialog

I want to make a registration form using jquery dialog but after I used jQuery Dialog and clicked the button to open the form the #btnsubmit Button doesn't work, before it's working can someone help me in my problem I have been trying to find the answer for like 2 days now and couldn't find the answer and I am newbie at all :P

js

```
$(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            width: 630,
            height: 630,
            draggable: false,
            resizable: false,
            modal: true
        });

        $("#btnaddnew").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

html

```
<div id="dialog" title="Add/Edit User">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="addpanel" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="registerform">
              <div class="formrow">
                <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="firstname">First Name</label></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txfirstname" runat="server" class="basetxt" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvfirstname" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txfirstname" style="margin-left:20px" /></td>
                </tr>
                </table>
              </div>

              <div class="formrow">
              <table>
              <tr>
                <td><label for="lastname">Last Name</label></td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txlastname" runat="server" class="basetxt" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvflastname" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Required" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txlastname" style="margin-left:20px" /></td>
              </tr>
              </table>
              </div>

              <div class="formrow">
              <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="address">Address</label></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txaddress" runat="server" class="basetxt" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvaddress" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txaddress" style="margin-left:20px" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </div>

              <div class="formrow">
              <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="age">Age</label></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txage" runat="server" class="basetxt" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvfage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txage" style="margin-left:20px" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revage" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Not Valid" ControlToValidate="txage" ValidationExpression="^[1-9]\d{0,2}$" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </div>

              <div class="formrow">
              <table>
                <tr>
                    <td><label for="mobile">Mobile #</label></td>
                    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txmobile" runat="server" class="basetxt" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rvfmobile" runat="server" Display="Dynamic" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Required" ControlToValidate="txmobile" style="margin-left:20px" />
                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="revmobile" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" ErrorMessage="Not Valid" Display="Dynamic" ControlToValidate="txmobile" ValidationExpression="^\d{11}" style="margin-left:20px" /></td>
                </tr>
              </table>
              </div>

              <div id="btnc2">
              <asp:Button ID="btnsubmit" runat="server" class="submitbtn" Text="Submit" onclick="btnsubmit_Click" style="margin-left: 10px" />
              <asp:Button ID="btnreset" runat="server" class="submitbtn" Text="Reset" 
                      style="margin-left: 30px" onclick="btnreset_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
              </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
```

Button Add New

```
<asp:Button ID="btnaddnew" runat="server" class="submitbtn" Text="Add New" 
                            style="margin-left: 10px; margin-top: 10px" onclick="btnaddnew_Click" CausesValidation="false" />
```

Comment: before what the it was working... what changes did you make.... whether the button is created dynamically

Comment: before, i didn't put the jquery dialog, and then i used dialog and after i clicked the button to open the dialog box and filled up the form nothing happens it should make me a user into my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [jQuery .on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to assign a click handler to the button element. Here is how the should look like:

```
$(function () {
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        width: 630,
        height: 630,
        draggable: false,
        resizable: false,
        modal: true
    });

    $("#dialog").on('click', '#btnaddnew', function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Why you have `onclick` attribute set when you're assigning the handler via jQuery method?

Comment: my project is to make a dialog box with a form inside that will ask your personal info and when you click on submit button it will add to my database . sorry I'm new in programming I am not good in reading codes yet

Comment: I used `onclick` to submit the form to my database and it adds a new user but after I used jQuery Dialog its not working anymore nothing happens everytime i hit submit button no user added to my database